# Intune/Endpoint Manager Line of Business (LOB) apps require developer mode on iOS16

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, intune, ios16

We have an iOS Line of Business Enterprise iOS app implemented using Xamarin. The provisioning profile and certificate is part of the iOS Enterprise Program. We deploy the IPA via InTune/Endpoint Manager. This works for all iPhones. However, on iOS 16, it requires that the user puts the phone into developer mode. How can we remove this requirement?

The user gets the following message: "Developer Mode Required. AppName requires Developer Mdoe to run. Until Developer Mode has been enabled, this app will not be available for use."

We understand that enterprise apps should be able to run on iOS16 without the need for Developer Mode. We understand that there was a bug in a beta version of iOS16 that did require Developer Mode for Test Flight apps. Our App is deployed via Intune (Endpoint Manager).

Comment: Since You and I suspect it's a apple issue. Did you put your questions in apple developer forum and requested a tech support?  https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

Comment: @kakaiikaka I did both.

Comment: Apparently, this is not something specific to intunes, I have also seen other blogs and such where people are facing issues with TestFlight apps asking for Developer mode. Could be a new thing Apple is adding with iOS 16